# Separate access to lower floor utility room

Tags: stairs, remodeling, rental

Hoping for some direction on this.

I am purchasing a half duplex and aim to convert the first floor into a 2 bedroom rental with a separate entrance.

- Main floor (my living space) is half a flight of stairs above ground
  and we would need access to the Utility room and storage (to the
  bottom of utility in the plan) located in First floor.
- Family room of 199 sq ft is at ground level.
- First floor is half a flight of stairs below ground and will have a separate kitchen and standalone laundry.

My current thinking is as follows:
Swap the direction of up and down stairs and wall off the separation at the entrance
Main floor entrance changed to the door from North east which is currently a balcony/patio

With this, the first floor will have a separate entrance through the foyer , I cant figure out a way for me to access the utility room without going through the rented unit.

I was hoping to hear your thoughts on this

Would it make sense to cut a portion of the kitchen/living room to make a L shape staircase leading to the utility storage (bottom right corner on the plan) or could there be a more easier solution.

Given the crazy home prices, having a ADU is critical cash flow support and was hoping the hive could show me some light :)

Have a good day.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Have you considered parceling off some space upstairs for utilities, perhaps off the formal dining?  You'll probably want a separate laundry for the upstairs unit, and you may very well *need* a separate water heater and air handler for this.

Comment: Is this being permitted under a local ADU rule, or being treated as a full-fledged duplex conversion by the local utilities and building department/AHJ, by the way?  Are you planning to separatemly meter the utilities, for that matter, and are the existing dryer, water heater, and heating system electric or gas?

Comment: Main floor shows stairs up—assume there's another floor above Main?  I can't see a way for you to get what you want without either an elevator or knocking out some walls and making some 1st floor rooms smaller.